# how can i deploy project from bitbucket to multiple domain?

Tags: php, laravel-5, version-control, ftp, cpanel

I have a billing web application & that application is used form different domain by different client. in my local server i am regularly upgrading feature of that web application. then after upgrading one feature i have to login each domain's cpanel or ftp then update particular code that i have changed.
this is very much embarrassing for me to update all different domain.
is there any easiest way to do that from bitbucket or any version control? or any other easiest way?
Thanks is advance.

Comment: ssh to the each server, and then git pull, or use some deployment system like atlasian pipelines, or jenkins

Comment: can you please provide me some tutorial link or any details.

Comment: @ShojibFlamon Asking for tutorials on Stack Overflow is off-topic.